# How to replace accent encodig with uft and iso-8859-1 latin

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Hi i am working with a webservice in android where I am receiving an array of strings i used this to convert the webservice response to utf-8

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        httpConn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

then I am using DocumentBuilderFactory to parse the xml and get all the data with a for my problem is that in the database there are some data in ISO-8859-1 and other with UTF-8  i use this function to remove the accent

```
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                    for (int x = 0; x < list; x++) {

                        Node a = nInterna.item(x);
                        if (a.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element element = (Element) a;

                            nidprod = element.getElementsByTagName("ccidclie");
                            line = (Element) nidprod.item(0);
                            temp = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                            id[x] = df.format(Float.parseFloat(temp));

                            nidprod = element.getElementsByTagName("ccname");
                            line = (Element) nidprod.item(0);
                            temp = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                            name[x] = deleteAccept(temp.toString().toUpperCase());

                        }
                    }
                }

public static String deleteAccept(String string) {
        String newstring = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
        return newstring;
    }
```

but is not working with iso-8859-1 then i try this way

```
String deleteAccept(String string) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        return new String(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
    }
```

to cover the two cases but it is not working  fine, my question is how can i replace the character that is encode with utf-8 and the character that is encode with iso-8859-1  thanks to all that can help me with an advice.

Comment: Are you receiving XML from this web service? If so, don't mess with the data, the encoding should be in the XML header and your XML reader should be able to handle it so that you have the correct characters in those strings.

Comment: Yeah i use this way String request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>searchCust><modesearch xsi:type='xsd:string'>" etc

Comment: But the problem is that in the dabase is a mix of data with utf-8 and iso-8859-1 so the response from webservices is a problem to remove the bad character encoding because i just work with the java side i can not touch the database.

Comment: Do look at the XML response. If the encoding is there in the first line, correctly, then all is well. The DB must make sure to send data correctly encoded, no matter how it is stored in the DB. (Unless, heavens forbid, the data is stored in a way that the DB is not aware of the encoding.)

Comment: Yeah i know that is a problem with the database maybe because they used to use an encoding like iso-8859-1 and then they changed to utf-8 because  for me they told me that i have to use utf-8 and i make it but i have to make work fine in my side does not matter if they can not change to work fine.

Comment: If i change the encoding in my side to iso-8859-1 it gives me  almost the half of data with a good encodign but the other half has the problem if i change the encoding to utf-8 the first data with encoding iso-8859-1 it comes with bad encodig  and the other comes fine thats why is a problem but i think that is a way to convert both  character in a good way, maybe i will try to conver to ascii the webservice response.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the data you are receiving?

Comment: If the DB is broken and you don't have any indication what is what, then you have a problem. If (if!) the data in the DB has been stored as ISO-8859-1 and is then sent, by the DB server, in an XML that encodes these characters using UTF-8, you might have a chance and try to re-translate the decoded UTF-8 into the original ISO-8859-1. But I'd need some such data that comes from the DB server (unmodified!) to investigate this.

Comment: Well this is an example: This is a name from db without modified JOSE VICUÃ±A but another name JUAN NUÑEZ it comes fine, the firts name should be like this JOSE VICUÑA can you see the problem why the firts name is bad enconding while the other one comes fine for the same character. The encoding from the data base in the xml comes in ISO-8859-1 so what can i do.

Comment: If i change the encondig to UTF-8 the firts name JOSE VICUÑA comes fine but JUAN NU�EZ comes with bad encoding how can i fix this situation because the half data comes with this problem and to change between encondings does not work.